# Always on Visible Workspace (or Sticky) button for Unity

Tags: unity, window-buttons

I would like to have the ability to have a button in Unity windows that causes the window to appear on all workspaces.  I know you can accomplish this by accessing the window menu and clicking 'Always on Visible Workspace' but I'd like a button like close, minimize, maximize.  I know when I first came to linux this feature existed on most window managers but it seems that it's been slowly disappearing.

Is there a way to bring this back?

P.S. The purpose of this is to have a **button** in the window titlebar that accomplishes this task.  I know this is possible through keyboard shortcuts and the window menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open `dconf-editor`, and go to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences` in the tree, you'll see a `button-layout` setting in the right pane. If you edit this setting, and add "stick" as one of the button strings in the setting, it should appear in the appropriate place on the window title bars. you probably want to put it after the `:` in the string, to have it on the far right, assuming you have the default settings of buttons on left in the title bars.

This may require changing the window manager theme to something capable of showing the button though. It seems many themes don't have support for it.

Comment: That's it!  I ended up figuring that part out overnight last night.  The tricky part is finding a theme that supports it.  Currently the only theme I've been able to find that supports the sticky button is Crux.  I'm currently working on editing the Ambiance xml file in an attempt to add a sticky button to this interface.  If I succeed I'll post the code here.

Comment: Did you manage to edit the Ambiance xml file?